# Why does my Save For Web gif keep coming out in a different color?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

I've created a smart object to put in my .mp4 video. I've layered an iPhone mockup over it. When I try to Save for Web to create a .gif, it keeps giving me this weird blue background. Even if I select the "Original" tab, it will still output a blue gif. How do I create a gif with colors true to the original video I'm uploading? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Does it only do this if you save as gif? What happens to jpg or png?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why it happens or how the color works in GIF, but here are two workarounds in case you don't know:

1. Try changing the mode to Perceptual (or try others) from Selective (under GIF dropdown)
2. If that doesn't work, manually edit (or add a new color buy removing that bluish white) the color in the color palette listed. You can first use eyedropper tool to note down the color code for the color causing problem and then later you can input it while adding or updating the color in the table.

To edit color in the table, simply double click it and enter the code/hex.

In your case you'll need to find that particular color which is bluish white. Seems to me the one highlighted by me.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, perceptual does not seem to work. However, I was able to set that light blue color that you circled as white. How did you know that was the correct color? I ask because now, the gray parts of the card are a weird beige color, and I'm not sure how exactly I can modify that color other than checking each square one by one to see if the hex codes match up.

Comment: @pyramidface I used eye dropper and checked if it matches with phone color or not. It was a guess. You don't need to see exact match, hex codes might not match exactly. But this one was closest so I came to know. Is there anything else in the GIF apart from phone screen? If no, try maybe using less colors? 128? Or reducing dither makes any difference?

Comment: Also, since it's a video, I feel that's why GIF has some 'trouble' picking exact colors. Normally, when we create GIF with high resolution images or create something from scratch in Photoshop, we don't usually see such problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem before ... I think. It happens when you work in Indexed color mode and you worked on a different image that already created the color table. Then you pasted this new screen and when you export it, it is giving you the same color table and it doesn't match the new image.
You don't need to work in indexed color mode. Work in RGB color mode and when you export as GIF, PS will calculate a new color table for each export.

I cropped a part of your original and at export I get this color table:

[image]

As you can see it works the way we expect it to work.